# Verify scrollbar side in IE

Tags: javascript

I would like to verify whether the scrollbar is placed on the left or on the right side of the window. Is it possible to obtain this info with JavaScript?

Comment: I am taking snapshot of a browser window (which includes the scroll bar) I would like then to draw rectangle around some html element (like edit box for example). I am taking the rect coordinates of the element throw getBoundingClientRect() function, but in case the scroll bar is on the left side of the browsing window the position is incorrect.